# Data augmentation for training dataset in gaussian process regression with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a Gaussian Process Regression problem with scikit-learn. In order to perform prediction I have a dataset that contains 10 different positions of a sensor in 3D coordinates: e.g.

Sensor1 coords:

```py
[[  30.1678 -173.569   725.724 ]
 [  29.9895 -173.34    725.76  ]
 [  29.9411 -173.111   725.768 ]
 [  29.9306 -173.016   725.98  ]
 [  29.6754 -172.621   725.795 ]
 [  29.5277 -172.274   725.903 ]
 [  29.585  -171.978   726.111 ]
 [  29.4114 -171.507   726.188 ]
 [  29.3951 -170.947   726.173 ]
 [  29.3577 -170.196   726.384 ]]
```

I perform the GPR with the Leave One Out technique, so that in each run I use 9 of the 3D coords. to train my model and test it on 1 coord. Then I change the permutation an continue.

In order to prevent the overfitting problem, I want to use data augmentation to enlarge (or add noise to) my training data. Most of the data augmentation techniques that I have seen are unfortunately used for images (random rotation, cropping, flipping etc.). My questions are:

1. Is there any method to do it for my data in python and how?
2. Is there any limitations that apply to the augmentation of my above data. How much noise can I add for a specific 3D coord.?
3. New noise data to add e.g. for column `x` should be between min `(29.585)` and max `(30.1678)` values. Am I correct? Or can it be done also row-wise?

**EDIT**

So, I have generated the noise manually.

```py
def use_data_augmentation(self, data):
   sizeOfData= 1000
        
   # Add noise to column x
   # Find min/max of each individual col
   noiseColXMin = np.min(data[:, 0])
   noiseColXMax = np.max(data[:, 0])

   # Generate random number between min/max
   addNoiseToColX = self.create_random_floats(noiseColXMin, noiseColXMax, sizeOfData)

   # Add noise to column y
   ...
   # Add noise to column z
   ...

   # Convert three 1D arrays to one 3D array
   addInputNoiseTotal = np.array([addNoiseToColX, addNoiseToColY, addNoiseToColZ]).T
   print('addInputNoiseTotal :\n', addInputNoiseTotal,
      '\nSDX:', np.std(addInputNoiseTotal[:, 0]),
      '\nSDY:', np.std(addInputNoiseTotal[:, 1]),
      '\nSDZ:', np.std(addInputNoiseTotal[:, 2]))

def create_random_floats(low, high, size):
   return [random.uniform(low, high) for _ in range(size)]
```

My problem is now: if I generate floats between the min/max values through `random.uniform(low, high, size)`, then the standard deviation of the noisy data is sometimes greater than `0.8` or `1.0`. Hence the RMS of the GPR prediction is worse. How can I set a limit, so that the SD of the generated floats cannot be greater than e.g. `0.2`?

Comment: No one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the variance of the sum of two **independent** random variables is the sum of their variance, you could compute the variance of your dataset, and use the facts that the variance of a uniform random variable is equal to `(high - low)**2 / 12`, and that the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, to select `high` and `low` values satisfying the condition

```py
np.sqrt(np.var(dataset) + (high - low)**2 / 12) <= 0.2
```

This should ensure that the standard deviation of the resulting noised data is less or equal than your thresholds of `0.2`.